# Function doesn't return the value

Tags: javascript

I have this function
`

```
let n = (index) => {
    if(index < 0){
        index = 0;  
    }
    return index;}
```

that must run inside of this function,

```
prev.addEventListener('click', function() {  
    index--;
    n(index);
    console.log(index);
});
```

but for some reasons it wouldn't work. It looks like it sets the value of index, but actually it doesn't

Comment: You're not assigning the result of your function call to anything. JavaScript is *pass-by-value*.

Answer (score 4):

You are forgetting to set your index to the value returned by the function.

```
prev.addEventListener('click', function() {  
    index--;
    index = n(index);
    console.log(index);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In here you have called the function `n(index)` but it's value isn't assigned anywhere, you have to assign it's value like below

```
let n = (index) => {
    if(index < 0){
        index = 0;  
    }
    return index;}

prev.addEventListener('click', function() {  
    index--;
    index = n(index); // This is where you have Assign it's Value
    console.log(index);
});
```